# Google Maps API GeoLocation not working for mobile

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mobile, browser, geolocation

I'm not really sure why the GeoLocation works on my PC, but not my iPhone ... I've got `sensor=true` within the script call to the API, but apart from that, I'm at a loss. Here's the entire script:

```
                <div id="info"></div>
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:908px; height:420px"></div>
                <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="10"/>
                <select id="radiusSelect">
                    <option value="5" selected>5mi</option>
                    <option value="15" selected>15mi</option>
                    <option value="25" selected>25mi</option>
                    <option value="100">100mi</option>
                    <option value="200">200mi</option>
                    <option value="4000">4000mi</option>
                </select>
                <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchLocations();">
                <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width:100%;visibility:hidden"></select></div>                   

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCe49sI29q0AVNo9iVvQ-lDlDwZpFZuA4o&sensor=true"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocate/geometa.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                var map;
                var markers = [];
                var infoWindow;
                var locationSelect;

                function load() {
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
                        zoom: 4,
                        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
                    });
                    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
                    locationSelect.onchange = function() {
                        var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
                        if (markerNum != "none") {
                            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
                        }
                    };

                    // geolocation
                    prepareGeolocation();
                    doGeolocation();
                }

                function doGeolocation() {
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionSuccess, positionError);
                    } else {
                        positionError(-1);
                    }
                }

                function positionError(err) {
                    var msg;
                    switch(err.code) {
                        case err.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                            msg = "Unable to find your location";
                            break;
                        case err.PERMISSION_DENINED:
                            msg = "Permission denied in finding your location";
                            break;
                        case err.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                            msg = "Your location is currently unknown";
                            break;
                        case err.BREAK:
                            msg = "Attempt to find location took too long";
                            break;
                        default:
                        msg = "Location detection not supported in browser";
                    }
                    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = msg;
                }

                function positionSuccess(position) {
                    // Centre the map on the new location
                    var coords = position.coords || position.coordinate || position;
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude);
                    map.setCenter(latLng);
                    map.setZoom(15);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: latLng,
                        title: 'Why, there you are!'
                    });
                    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'Looking for <b>' +
                    coords.latitude + ', ' + coords.longitude + '</b>...';

                    // And reverse geocode.
                    (new google.maps.Geocoder()).geocode({latLng: latLng}, function(resp) {
                        var place = "You're around here somewhere!";
                        if (resp[0]) {
                            var bits = [];
                            for (var i = 0, I = resp[0].address_components.length; i < I; ++i) {
                                var component = resp[0].address_components[i];
                                if (contains(component.types, 'political')) {
                                    bits.push('<b>' + component.long_name + '</b>');
                                }
                            }
                            if (bits.length) {
                                place = bits.join(' > ');
                            }
                            marker.setTitle(resp[0].formatted_address);
                        }
                        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = place;
                    });
                }

                function contains(array, item) {
                    for (var i = 0, I = array.length; i < I; ++i) {
                        if (array[i] == item) return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                function searchLocations() {
                    console.log("searching locations...");
                    var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
                        } else {
                            alert(address + ' not found');
                        }
                    });
                }

                function clearLocations() {
                    //infoWindow.close();
                    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        markers[i].setMap(null);
                    }
                    markers.length = 0;

                    locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.value = "none";
                    option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
                    locationSelect.appendChild(option);
                    locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
                }

                function searchLocationsNear(center) {
                    clearLocations();

                    var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
                    /* var searchUrl = 'phpsqlajax_search.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius; */
                    var searchUrl = 'http://dev-imac.local/phpsqlajax_search.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
                    console.log(searchUrl);
                    downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
                        var xml = parseXml(data);
                        var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                        for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
                            var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
                            var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
                            var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
                            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

                                createOption(name, distance, i);
                                createMarker(latlng, name, address);
                                bounds.extend(latlng);
                        }
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);
                    });
                }

                function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
                    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: latlng
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infoWindow.setContent(html);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);
                }

                function createOption(name, distance, num) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.value = num;
                    option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
                    locationSelect.appendChild(option);
                }

                function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
                    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                    new XMLHttpRequest;

                    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (request.readyState == 4) {
                            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                            callback(request.responseText, request.status);
                        }
                    };

                    request.open('GET', url, true);
                    request.send(null);
                }

                function parseXml(str) {
                    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                        doc.loadXML(str);
                        return doc;
                    } else if (window.DOMParser) {
                        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
                    }
                }

                function doNothing() {}

                window.onload = load();

                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
```

should be:

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
```

but that should cause it to fail in your PC as well.

Other than that, your `<script>` section should be in the `<head>` section of the document and not in the `<body>`. Maybe the iPhone browser is more strict about this than the browser on your PC. What browser(s) are you using in each system? (I'm guessing you're using IE on the PC. Have you tried other browsers?)

Comment: Safari. And the PC or Mac is not an issue at all... it's just my iPhone.

Comment: I am not familiar with the iPhone browser, but in the case of Android the browsers are very "minified", (light weight for mobile), which means they are less tolerant of minor errors and your code needs to be more standard compliant.

Comment: Well, this code is literally all from Google ... no customizations. So I'm not understanding what the issues are.

Comment: I doubt it is written by Google because it has the problems I pointed out in my answer. Does the iPhone browser have an error log?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3 ... https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation ... literally written by Google. And even with Safari's Debug console on, there's no error.

Comment: And even when you go to: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation on your mobile device, it doesn't work. Not making much sense to me...

Comment: The code in the link you posted uses mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, as I pointed out in my answer, so your code is **not** original from Google.

Comment: It is in the first link I sent. This is not really something that I want to argue about. Thanks for trying to help.